# In how many ways can we put $31$ people in $3$ rooms?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can we put $31$ people in $3$ rooms such that each room has an odd number of people ?

---

Can I apply generating functions here or Sterling's formula of $2$nd kind or any other method ?

---

www.math.toronto.edu/szegedy/solutions.pdf

The above link gives an approach, but I am not familiar with it .

Comment: Put a person on each room, after that pair the other $28$ people. The stars and bars method applies straightforwardy and gives you $\binom{15}{2} = 105$.

Comment: @Crostul "each room has an odd number of people" -> I think stars and bars can't help here .

Comment: @Crostul Moreover, people and rooms are distinguishable , I think so. They haven't said it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*@trueblueannil demonstrated that my original solution was incorrect since I had overlooked the fact that arrangements within each room did not matter.  I have edited my solution to fix the problem.*

**Preliminary remarks:**  The *Binomial Theorem* states that 
$$(x + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{n - k}y^k$$
Substituting $1$ for both $x$ and $y$ yields
$$2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}1^{n - k}1^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$
Since $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of subsets of size $k$ and a subset of a set with $n$ elements has up to $n$ elements, the preceding statement says that a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets.  If we instead set $x = 1$ and $y = -1$ in the Binomial Theorem, we obtain
$$0 = 0^n = (1 + (-1))^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}1^{n - k}(-1)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k$$
from which it follows that the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements that have an odd number of elements (the negative terms) is equal to the number of subsets with an even number of elements (the positive terms).

**Solution:**  There are $\binom{31}{1}$ ways to select one person to be placed in the first room.  Choosing who among the remaining people is placed in the second room determines who goes in the third room.  Since an odd number of people must be placed in each room, we can select $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$, $11$, $13$, $15$, $17$, $19$, $21$, $23$, $25$, $27$, or $29$ of the remaining $30$ people to be placed in the second room.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which one person is placed in the first room is 
$$\binom{31}{1}\left[\binom{30}{1} + \binom{30}{3} + \cdots + \binom{30}{27} + \binom{30}{29}\right] = \binom{31}{1}2^{30 - 1} = \binom{31}{1}2^{29}$$

There are $\binom{31}{3}$ ways to select three of the $31$ people to be placed in the first room.  Since the number placed in each room must be odd, the number of people who can be placed in the second room is $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$, $11$, $13$, $15$, $17$, $19$, $21$, $23$, $25$, or $27$.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which exactly three people are placed in the first room is 
$$\binom{31}{3}\left[\binom{28}{1} + \binom{28}{3} + \cdots + \binom{28}{25} + \binom{28}{27}\right] = \binom{31}{3}2^{28 - 1} = \binom{31}{3}2^{27}$$

Continuing in this way, we obtain the number of arrangements in which an odd number of the $31$ people are placed in each room, which is 
$$\binom{31}{2}2^{29} + \binom{31}{3}2^{27} + \binom{31}{5}2^{25} + \binom{31}{7}2^{23} + \binom{31}{9}2^{21} + \binom{31}{11}2^{19} + \binom{31}{13}2^{17} + \binom{31}{15}2^{15} + \binom{31}{17}2^{13} + \binom{31}{19}2^{11} + \binom{31}{21}2^9 + \binom{31}{23}2^7 + \binom{31}{25}2^5 + \binom{31}{27}2^3 + \binom{31}{29}2^1$$ $$= 154,418,349,070,986$$

**Note:**  If we were dealing with indistinguishable objects, we could apply the following argument.

Let $x_1$ be the number of people placed in the first room; let $x_2$ be the number of people placed in the second room; let $x_3$ be the number of people placed in the third room.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 31 \tag{1}$$
Since each $x_k$ is a positive odd integer, if we set $x_k = 2y_k + 1$ for $1 \leq k \leq 3$, then each $y_k$ is a nonnegative integer, and 
\begin{align*}
2y_1 + 1 + 2y_2 + 1 + 2y_3 + 1 & = 31\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 & = 28\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 14 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with the same number of solutions that equation 1 has in the positive odd integers.  The number of solutions of equation 2 can be found using the formula for [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).  However, people are distinguishable.

Comment: Multiplication by $31!$ is not correct. Consider, say, $5$ people put in $3$ non-empty rooms. There are only $2$ patterns possible, $3-1-1$ or $2-2-1$, with $3\cdot 20 + 3\cdot 30 = 150$ total ways, while multiplying $\binom{5-1}{3-1}\times 5! = 720$

Comment: @trueblueanil  Thank you for pointing out my error, which I have corrected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am finding this difficult to catch up. Is there any other method or provide some references to the same type of problems.

Comment: You're welcome ! (+1)

Comment: @trueblueanil Can this me done by any other method ? Or atleast provide some references to other problems like this .

Comment: @Garrick: Use of generating functions is the standard way; Taussig has solved it creatively in another way; I'm afraid I can't think of any other simple way.

Comment: @trueblueanil Can you answer by generating functions .

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: The solution is the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in $(x+\frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots )^3$ multiplied by $31!$.

Using $x+\frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, we can easily get the answer as $\frac{3^{31}-3-3+3^{31}}{8} =\frac{3^{31}-3}{4}$.

Comment: which would be 154418349070986.

Comment: Yes, that is actually the solution from Toronto University, but I don't know from where it came .

Answer (score 1):

Fix$1$ person in each &then consider two people as one and the solution  would be equivalent to the no of non negative solutions of $$x_1+x_2+x_3=14$$

Where $x_i$ represent rooms.

Now count the ways to make 14 pairs &multiply with the no of solutions found about.